# Date comparison to find which is bigger in C

Tags: c, date, comparison

I want to know how to find which is bigger date using a C program

kindly help me out plz....

Comment: How are the dates being supplied to you?

Comment: Comparing `sizeof ( date1 ) > sizeof ( date2 )` tells you which is bigger, or possibly comparing the date to my wedding anniversary, which was a big date for me? Earlier/later is the normal way of comparing dates, since magnitude depends on where you're counting from, and is not necessarily meaningful.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`difftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/difftime) function:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  time_t date1, date2;
  // initialize date1 and date2...

  double seconds = difftime(date1, date2);
  if (seconds > 0) {
    printf("Date1 > Date2\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If your dates are not of type `time_t`, you can use the function [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) to convert them.

Comment: You are comparing time and not date.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct date 
{
   int month;
   int date;
   int year;
};


int main(void)
{
    int i=compare_dates (struct date d1, struct date d2);
    switch(i)
    {
       case -1:
         printf("%d/%d/%d is earlear date than %d/%d %d", D1.day, D1.month, D1.year, D2.day
       case 1: 
         printf("%d/%d/%d is later date than %d/%d/%d",D1.day,D1.month,D1.year,D2.day…
       case 0: 
         printf("%d/%d/%d is the same date than %d/%d/%d", D1.day, D1.month, D1.year, D2.day
     }
   return 0;
}


int compare_dates (struct date d1, struct date d2)
{
    if (d1.year < d2.year)
       return -1;

    else if (d1.year > d2.year)
       return 1;

    if (d1.year == d2.year)
    {
         if (d1.month<d2.month)
              return -1;
         else if (d1.month>d2.month)
              return 1;
         else if (d1.day<d2.day)
              return -1;
         else if(d1.day>d2.day)
              return 1;
         else
              return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (d1.year = d2.year)` should have `==` i think :-)

Comment: Isn't that `if (d1.year == d2.year)` redundant, since if you reach this point of the function, then you will know that the year is the same?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to know which is bigger, you don't need go through all this.  You can just prioritize the values and compare them. Just add coefficients to month and year that is bigger than highest day possible. For example, say that a month is 100 times more important than the day and a year is 2000 times more important than a day. Just calculate the score of the dates and compare them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int day1, day2, month1, month2, year1, year2;

    printf("Enter first date (dd/mm/yyyy) => "); scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day1, &month1, &year1);
    int prioritedScore1 = day1 + month1*100 + year1*2000;
    printf("Enter second date (dd/mm/yyyy) => "); scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day2, &month2, &year2);
    int prioritedScore2 = day2 + month2*100 + year2*2000;

    if(prioritedScore1 > prioritedScore2){
        printf("Bigger date is => %d/%d/%d", day1, month1, year1);
    } else if(prioritedScore2 > prioritedScore1){
        printf("Bigger date is => %d/%d/%d", day2, month2, year2);
    } else{
        printf("Dates are same.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can always use a long integer in order to get rid of possible bugs when user enters so high numbers like 2147484 as year.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more information about what you want to achieve ? Because comparing date is really easy. After all, they are just number of seconds (or milli, micro, nano, ...) since a given past date, or a structure containing year, month, day, ... Whatever the format, the comparison should be pretty easy to perform.

Maybe you want to compare two date given by the user as strings (something like "2011-03-12 18:38") ? Then, you can use `strptime` to convert the string to a `struct tm`, and then do the comparison.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int parse_date(char* date, struct tm* tm)
{
    char* format;
    char* formats[] = {
        "%F %I", /* "2011-03-12 06:38:05 AM" */
        "%F %T", /* "2011-03-12 18:38:05" */
        "%F %R", /* "2011-03-12 18:38" */
        NULL,
    };

    for (format = formats[0]; format; ++ format) {
        if (strptime(date, format, &tm)) {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    float diff;

    char* date1;
    char* date2;

    struct tm tm1;
    struct tm tm2;

    time_t time1;
    time_t time2;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: compare-date date1 date2\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    date1 = argv[1];
    date2 = argv[2];

    if (!parse_date(date1, &tm1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unsupported date: %s\n", date1);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (!parse_date(date2, &tm1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "unsupported date: %s\n", date2);
        exit(1);
    }

    time1 = mktime(&tm1);
    time2 = mktime(&tm2);
    diff = difftime(time1, time2);

    printf("%s %c %s\n",
        date1,
        (diff < 0 ? '<' : (diff > 0 ? '>' : '==')),
        date2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say in which format you have the date, so I will name two common examples:

- If you are using GNU lib-c (or MinGW) and query the time with:

  ```
  time_t time (time_t *result)
  ```

  Then `time_t` is just a `long int`, numbers of seconds since `epoch` and you can subtract one date from the other to find out the number of seconds difference.
- If you are using the Windows API and have a filetime-structure:

  ```
  typedef struct _FILETIME {
      DWORD dwLowDateTime;
      DWORD dwHighDateTime;
  } FILETIME, *PFILETIME;
  ```

  you can cast the pointer to a pointer to `ULARGE_INTEGER`, and subtract that one giving you the number of 100-nanosecond intervals difference.

Comment: time_t is equally valid on Windows compilers. Your answer confused me into thinking it wasn't available in Visual C++ compilers...

Comment: @rubenvb yes. these are just examples.

Comment: `time_t` is a type in standard C89 and is therefore supported by MSVC as well as Unix C compilers.  There are many different sub-second time structures though.

Comment: indeed. these are just examples. we just have to wait for OP to finally tell us how he queried the date; probably he will tell us that he uses a string containing the date on the mayan calendar encoded in roman numerals :-)