# Datetime comparison in C

Tags: c, datetime

I want to compare datetime in C. I googled but I didn't get any proper solution. I am having datetime in string format i.e date1 = "2014-02-13 12:22:21" and date2 = "2014-02-10 12:22:21".
Now, I want comparison b/w date1 and date2.
Please suggest me proper solution.

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik, That is C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Date comparison to find which is bigger in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283120/date-comparison-to-find-which-is-bigger-in-c)

Comment: As you have a very nice format (AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), just use strcmp, with returns a positive or negative value, depending on lexicographically compare.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `strcmp`.  It works because with this particular date/time format, the lexicographical order is the same as the chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't run this on the critical path, Then just use `strncmp()`. Else, if speed is important, parse it with `strptime()`+`mktime()` into UTC uint64_t microseconds/milliseconds since epoch and compare those. I would also make sure timezones are taken into account consistently across the code base.

To clarify the point raised in the comment - whether to prefer string comparison to timestamp comparison (paying parsing overhead) is solely determined by the usage pattern and can be benchmarked in a simple synthetic test.

Comment: The comparison may be faster, but is it still faster if you count the overhead of calling `strptime`?

Comment: I assume everything is benchmarked before used as it is the usage pattern that determines whether parsing overhead is worth paying or not, inline with best practices of dynamic programming