# Display error when date is different in C programming

Tags: c, text-files

So what I'm trying to do is to display an error message whenever the "Date of Expiry" is before the "Date of manufacture". So for example if I enter the year 2000 for manufacture and 1999 for expiry, then it should display an error like "Date of expiry cannot be before date of manufacture" I'm still learning C programming and any help would be much appreciated. I'm currently using Dev C++ as compiler

EDIT: I need the date to be in DD/MM/YYYY format

Below is my code

```
void add_medicine() //Function to add customer
{
    system("cls");
gotoxy(15,5);
printf("================= ADD NEW MEDICINE ================");
char medicinename[50];
char medavailability[20];
char companyname[100];
char dom[50];
char doe[50];
int price [50];


    gotoxy(15,7);
    printf("Enter Medicine Name:");
    scanf("%s",&medicinename);

    gotoxy(15,9);
    printf("Enter Medicine Availability (Yes/No): ");
    scanf("%s",&medavailability);

    gotoxy(15,11);
    printf("Enter Company Name: ");
    scanf("%s", &companyname);

    gotoxy(15,13);
    printf("Enter Date of Manufacture: ");
    scanf("%s", &dom);

    gotoxy(15,15);
    printf("Enter Date of Expiry: ");
    scanf("%s", &doe);

    gotoxy(15,17);
    printf("Enter Price: ");
    scanf("%s", &price);


const char *fil  = "Medicines/"; //Creates file in an existing folder
const char *exec = ".txt";
char filename[50];
snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "%s%s%s", fil, medicinename, exec);

FILE *fp; //Adding all data to the file

fp =fopen(filename,"w+");

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", medicinename);

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", medavailability);

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", companyname);

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", dom);

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", doe);

fprintf(fp, "%s\n", price);

fclose(fp);

gotoxy(15,19);
printf("================= NEW MEDICINE ADDED! =============");
gotoxy(15,21);
printf("PRESS ANY KEY TO GO BACK");
getch();
adminMenu(0);
}
```

Comment: Where are you doing the comparison between date of manufacture and the expire date?

Comment: Thats the thing i'm trying to do @gsamaras

Comment: That is rather more code than necessary to show your attempt - pick out just the code you are asking about - don't make us search for it.  Moreover posting all your code will attract numerous comments about parts not related to your question, which may help you, but are just noise for SO.

Comment: @Clifford i edited my code

Comment: @Javy14 : The point is you _have not tried_.  You need to show your attempt at a solution so we can see where you are going wrong.  You need to convert the date strings into a numeric timestamp such as `time_t`.  Unfortunately yu have not forced your user to input the date in any specific format, so conversion will be complex.  Enter day, month, year separately will make it easier.  If you are only entering dates as a year as in your question text, you can accept input as an integer or convert the string, then it is just arithmetic.

Comment: What do the dates look like? If you use the ISO-standard format, like 2018-06-08, you can just do a string-compare (`strcmp`) and get the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compare strings in C, you need to use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), like this:

```
if(strcmp(doe, dom) < 0)
    printf("Date of expiry cannot be before date of manufacture\n");
```

---

However, since these dates are just the years, why not use `int` instead of `char` arrays?

Like this:

```
int doe, dom;
if(doe < dom)
    printf("Date of expiry cannot be before date of manufacture\n");
```

---

PS: If your dates are in a format, then read [Date comparison to find which is bigger in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283120/date-comparison-to-find-which-is-bigger-in-c).

Comment: You did not mention that in your question @Javy14, I updated my answer now, hope that helps. =)

Comment: Thank you very much @gsamaras