# How to check if a string date has passed a certain date

Tags: c, date

I have these strings:

```
yy = "19";
mm = "05";
dd = "31";
```

These represent the creation date of a certain object in my project. This object expires after one month. How do I check if the object has expired already?

(I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283120/date-comparison-to-find-which-is-bigger-in-c) but thought there might be another way to do it.)

UPDATE: the string date apparently represent the actual expiry date

Comment: Asked and answered at the same time?

Comment: I have a suspicion that "one month later than now" will never be earlier than "now".

Comment: upon recheck, the string date is the actual expiry date. so comparing its long value with the current date's long value will work. i updated the question to reflect this. thanks @Brendan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the date format "yymmdd" so I can convert it to type `long` and do a simple number comparison.

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s%s%s", yy, mm, dd);
expiryDate = atol(buffer);

// get current date of format "yymmdd" as well
// getCurrentDate() is my function that gets the date from my SDK
currentDate = getCurrentDate();

if(expiryDate >= currentDate)
{
    // expired object!
}
```

Comment: What/Where is `getCurrentDate()`?

Comment: hello @SouravGhosh. it gets the current date of my device using the device manufacturer's SDK. but i guess for this code snippet to be useful to others, they can replace it with their own getCurrentDate() implementation.

Comment: If you're serious about doing this, please, please, please don't use two-digit years.  Use `2019`, not `19`.

Comment: thanks @SteveSummit. let's leave your comment here as a note to the readers. cheers!